# Hashmap problem adding strings from a file in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a problem adding strings into hashmap in java. My file has inside the following

[image]

On top it has comments and after that it has two number in each line. I want to remove comments or just ignore them and set each number into the hashmap only once, so i have to check for reappearance. I wrote the code below but i have problems with counting. SOMETIMES it's random. 
I have set a static counter "mapcounter" that is the value of the map that after every key insertion i increase by one. Here is the code:

```
    String line = filemap.nextLine();
    while(filemap.hasNextLine()) {

        if(!line.startsWith("#")) {
            String word[]=new String[2];
            word[0]=filemap.next();
            word[1]=filemap.next();

            if(!map.containsKey(word[0])){
                map.put(word[0],mapcounter++);
            }
            if(!map.containsKey(word[1])){
                map.put(word[1],mapcounter++);
            }
        }
        line = filemap.nextLine();
    }
```

Some other details. I open the file with scanner and our file pointer is "filemap".
 i treat the numbers as Strings ! There are the keys of the map
 So when i print the value of the key "30" i get correct 0 , as it is the first key to add.
 when i check the value of key "1412" i get a number like 500+. And i don't know why, also for key "3" i get value 6.....
Any ideas??

Extra explanation:
i want to keep each different Number from both columns into the hash map so i can arrange them a value. From 0 to 1,2,3,4,5,.......,1890,..... and so on. Like that 30=0, 1412=1, 3352=2, 5254=3, 5543=4,7478=5,3=6, and so on. If a key appears again i want to ignore it because already has a value. Also i want to keep and from the second column, not just the first one. That's why i have word[2] Thanks for your help

Comment: You've already read the line into `line`.  Don't call `next()` to grab more off the scanner, parse the data out of the line you've already read.  `next()` in this case is going to be grabbing ahead of the line you've just got.

Comment: Since maps can't handle duplicate keys, what are you doing each time you encounter say 30 in your list?

Comment: i had in mind to split the words that's why i use next()

what should i do for the duplicate? i mean i don't add them. and i think in the next line the are going to be replaced with the next word...I think

Comment: The best thing you can do to help us help you is to re-edit your question and explain to us how you use the data shown, and what the output should look like (or how you want to store it).  What would the map look like after some values are added?

Comment: i want to keep each different Number from both columns into the hash map so i can arrange them a value. From 0 to 1,2,3,4,5,.......,1890,..... and so on. If a key appears again i want to ignore it because already has a value. Also i want to keep and from the second column, not just the first one. That's why i have word[2] 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on new information provided in comments.

Given a

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can read in two values and update the counter based on their occurrence

```
        int mapcounter = 0;
        String line = filemap.nextLine();
        while(filemap.hasNextLine()) {
            if(!line.startsWith("#")) {

               // split the two node column into two values.
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");

                if(!map.containsKey(word[0])){
                    map.put(word[0],mapcounter++);
                }
                if(!map.containsKey(word[1])){
                    map.put(word[1],mapcounter++);
                }
            }
            line = filemap.nextLine();
        }
```

In my first answer, I totally misunderstood what you wanted.  Your solution was fine except for your two next() statements.  You need eliminate them and replace with a `String.split` to split the line into the two words.  The `\\s+` is a regular expression that splits on one or more spaces.

Comment: so with map.computeIfAbsent i remove my 2 if(!map.containsKey( word[0]) ) statements.... i will test this

Comment: nice , but what that line is oding exacly " map.computeIfAbsent(word[0], v-> word[1]); "
It confuses me with the second argument v->word[1], in comparison with the comment above it

Comment: If the key is not mapped to a value, the key and value are added.  The next time a value wants to be added for the same key, it will be ignored because the key is already there.  I may have misworded my answer so I will fix it.

Comment: but why you use both word[0] and word[1]. o dont get it. places word[1] you say in comment if not pressent. so what is the role of word[0]. 
also i need to count how many different keys(numbers from both columns and all rows) are added in the map! That's why i use a counter in may code calles mapcounter

Comment: i have read a bit for computeIfAbsent and  i think it correct like that
map.computeIfAbsent(word[0], k-> mapcounter );
At last i cannot do that. my answer above is wrong, it wont let me use mapcounter

Comment: No fix yet. if you have a better implementation tell me

Comment: @Psz_13  Please see my updated answer.  I believe it does what you want.